# In Markdown, how do I start a line with a number without creating a list?

Tags: markdown

I want to start a line with a number in Markdown without it creating a list.

```
1. so my next line

will be parallel to the first

    1. not indented  

like this
```

Answer (score 93):

From the [Markdown Syntax Documentation](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#list):

> It’s worth noting that it’s possible to trigger an ordered list by accident, by writing something like this:
>
> 1986. What a great season.
>
> In other words, a number-period-space sequence at the beginning of a line. To avoid this, you can backslash-escape the period:
>
> 1986\. What a great season.

Comment: Weird syntax. Why cant we simply escape the number (`\1986.`)? This would be intuitive for me, seeing the complete `1986.` as the command, not the single`.`.

Comment: Or use a dash... 1 - Hello there.

Answer (score 9):

Use an invisible character:

```
&#8291;1.
```

I did this as my MD processor didn't support the `1\.` escaping notation used in Ethan's answer here.